# Unable to access site after importing DB

Tags: craft3, database, installation, craft2

I am installing a repo locally, and everything runs smoothly and I am able to see the site and login to my admin. But when I import my DB then visit my site: I get the error message "Site unavailable".

When I visit my admin area I see the message: "To complete the update, some changes must be made to your database." I click proceed and see the message "Craft couldn’t backup the database. How would you like to proceed?".

I am using Craft 3. But the DB I am importing from uses the older 'craft_' prefix, which I defined in the setup. Am stumped on how to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

Ended up getting this resolved, by downloading DB from Craft staging site and importing, instead of using Sequel Pro. Also make sure your configs in general.php are correct.

Answer (score 0):

> But when I import my DB then visit my site: I get the error message "Site unavailable".

You get that because it's a front-end site request and Craft needs to make updates to the database that can be triggered by the Control Panel.

> I click proceed and see the message "Craft couldn’t backup the database. How would you like to proceed?".

That's because Craft uses [mysqldump](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html) (if you're using MySQL) to perform database backups and the path to that currently isn't available to PHP in your environment. The easiest way to fix it is to add the path to `mysqldump` to your system PATH environment varible.

Alternatively, you can manually perform a database backup using your favorite database client, and click the "Continue anyway" button to let Craft finish performing the update.